# Flutter height of list widget is not reducing

Tags: flutter

I am trying to reduce height and width of container of a widget but its not reducing.

Code

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  List datesData = [
    
      '09:00 am - 10:00 am',
      '10:00 am - 11:00 am',
      '11:00 am - 12:00 am',
      '12:00 am - 01:00 am',
      '01:00 am - 02:00 am',
      '02:00 am - 03:00 am',
      '03:00 am - 04:00 am',
      '04:00 am - 05:00 am'
    
  ];

  List<Widget> textWidgetList = List<Widget>();

  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> textWidgetList = List<Widget>(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      textWidgetList.add(
        Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 200,
          color: Colors.grey,
          child: Center(
            child: Text(datesData[i].toString()),
            )
        ),
      );
    }

    return   GridView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                mainAxisSpacing: 1,
                crossAxisSpacing: 1,
              ),
              children: textWidgetList,
            
          );
  }
}
```

I need to show grid view like this

[image]

its showing like this

[image]

I try to give height and width to the container but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

The width of the children will be determined by the number of columns (`crossAxisCount`) in the `GridView`, as well as the `crossAxisSpacing` and `Padding`. Use `childAspectRatio` to achieve the desired height.

```
GridView(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
  shrinkWrap: true,
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    mainAxisSpacing: 1,
    crossAxisSpacing: 1,
    // use ratio to adjust height
    childAspectRatio: 3,
  ),
  children: textWidgetList,
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
its because grid items size, no need to set container height for this reason.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

      final double itemHeight = (size.height - kToolbarHeight - 24) / 2;
      final double itemWidth = size.width / 2;
 

    List<Widget> textWidgetList = List<Widget>(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      textWidgetList.add(
        Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 200,
          color: Colors.grey,
          child: Center(
            child: Text(datesData[i].toString()),
            )
        ),
      );
    }

    return   GridView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              shrinkWrap: true,
             childAspectRatio: (itemWidth / itemHeight),

              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                mainAxisSpacing: 1,
                crossAxisSpacing: 1,
              ),
              children: textWidgetList,
            
          );
  }
}
```